# lme4 fails to calculate random intercepts with no warnings

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

Having a peculiar issue where given 2 datasets with the same exact formatting, 2 models specified exactly the same way don’t produce the same random effects structure. The design of the data is such that each there are 48 unique subjects each with a single observation in 4 conditions. Outcome variable is the ‘dv’ column, predictor variable is the ‘cond’ column, and grouping variable is the ‘sub’ column.

The first model runs as expected, with subject level random intercepts, as examined using coef(model), while the other assumes a fixed intercept for all subjects. This is despite the fact that both models are specified identically. There are no convergence, or variance issue warnings and subjects do in fact have different means (average response across all 4 conditions), so the intercepts should vary.

Taking out the first 33 rows of the dataset (which is first 33 subjects within condition 0) make lme4 calculate random intercepts properly. I can’t seem to isolate this to a weird data point however, and all types and code is identical between models. Totally stuck as to why a weird data point (if that’s really the problem) should be confusing how lme4 calculates random effects.

See code below to reproduce issues with the following data files:
[data files (zip)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfpjinjgp8fdzv5/data_files.zip?dl=0)

```
library('lme4')
data_dir = '/Path/to/data/dir/'
#Load in data and set types
goodDat = read.csv(paste(data_dir,'ROI_2_noX.csv',sep=""))
goodDat$dv <-as.numeric(goodDat$dv)
goodDat$cond <- as.factor(goodDat$cond)
#4 levels make the first the reference 
goodDat$cond <- relevel(goodDat$cond,ref="0");
goodDat$sub <- as.factor(goodDat$sub)

#Same for bad example
badDat = read.csv(paste(data_dir,'ROI_3_noX.csv',sep=""))
#badDat = badDat[34:192,] #This works! uncomment it to see the proper random effects in the second model
badDat$dv <-as.numeric(badDat$dv)
badDat$cond <- as.factor(badDat$cond)
#4 levels make the first the reference
badDat$cond <- relevel(badDat$cond,ref="0");
badDat$sub <- as.factor(badDat$sub)

#Good model with expected random intercepts for subjects
model = lmer('dv~cond + (1|sub)',data=goodDat)
summary(model)
coef(model)

#Bad model with no subject random intercepts
model = lmer('dv~cond + (1|sub)',data=badDat)
summary(model)
coef(model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some circumstances the numerical estimation of the `lmer` parameters can be problematic. Changing parameters of the optimization algorithm with `lmerControl` or changing optimization algorithm could be a good way to solve the problem.

Below I try to estimate the parameters of the mixed-effect model on `badDat` with the `lme` function in the package `nlme` using the `optim` optimizer:

```
library(nlme)   
model2 = lme(fixed = dv ~ cond, random = ~ 1 | sub, data=badDat,
          control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
summary(model2b)

#####################
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: badDat 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  522.909 542.3277 -255.4545

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | sub
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 0.008620485 0.9036019

Fixed effects: dv ~ cond 
                  Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.19443385 0.1304296 141  1.4907183  0.1383
cond1       -0.00074922 0.1844470 141 -0.0040620  0.9968
cond2        0.15675844 0.1844470 141  0.8498835  0.3968
cond3        0.19542024 0.1844470 141  1.0594928  0.2912
 Correlation: 
      (Intr) cond1  cond2 
cond1 -0.707              
cond2 -0.707  0.500       
cond3 -0.707  0.500  0.500

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-3.9838652 -0.6574260 -0.0112212  0.6733073  3.8501157 

Number of Observations: 192
Number of Groups: 48
```

The estimated random intercepts are very similar, but not all equal like before:

```
coef(model2b)

################
   (Intercept)         cond1     cond2     cond3
4    0.1943937 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
5    0.1942458 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
6    0.1944388 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
7    0.1943862 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
10   0.1945275 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
11   0.1943091 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
12   0.1943333 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
13   0.1941818 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
14   0.1942539 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
15   0.1947154 -0.0007492168 0.1567584 0.1954202
```

I hope this could help you.